Question about Hilbert Basis and closure of the linear span.
While reading about Hilbert Basis, I have struggled to come up with an example of a Hilbert space $H$ which has a (countable) orthonormal system where the (infinite) linear span is not the whole space $H$, but the closure is. Do you know of any such example? In every definition of a Hilbert Basis I've seen, we just require the infinite linear span of all basis elements to be dense in the space.
I know this question is very general but I'm hoping someone can help me clear up some confusion. Here is the Wikipedia article part I'm referring to.


The linear span the article is referring to is the set of all finite linear combinations of the elements of the base.

And what you call the "infinite linear span" (an unusual name AFAIK) is the closure of the linear span. So, saying that the linear span is dense in $H$  is the same as saying that your "infinite linear span" equals $H$. One never "require[s] the infinite linear span of all basis elements to be dense". You must have misread "every definition of a Hilbert Basis [you]'ve seen".

I give a more thorough answer for better understanding of the concepts.
First, let's understand why we need a notion of Hilbert base and why Hamel base is not sufficient for analytically analyzing infinite dimensional vector spaces (eg. function spaces).
Every vector space $V$ has a Hamel basis $B$, which is a set of linearly independent vectors such that any element of $V$ can be written as finite linear combination of elements from $B$. Vector spaces of finite dimension $n$ have a Hamel basis consisting of exactly $n$ vectors however things start to get messy when we go to infinite dimensional vector spaces. Note that Hilbert spaces are Banach spaces. By Baire theorem one can show that any infinite-dimensional Banach space has a non-countable Hamel basis. Now if we would like to prove a property about $V$ using its Hamel basis we would be in trouble because the only thing we know about Hamel basis is that it exists. The basis itself is unconstructive and is equivalent to the axiom of choice.
However, Hilbert Basis comes to the rescue. We can construct a countable set of elements $H$ (eg. Fourier basis) such that every element from $V$ can be written as an infinite countable sum of elements from $H$. By the definition of convergence, it is equivalent to say that for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite set of elements from $H$ (just a truncation of the converging series) such that its sum lies $\epsilon$ close to the element from $V$. This is the same as saying that finite linear span of elements from $H$ is dense in $V$, but only a closure of this linear span (passing to the limit in the series) is the whole space $V$.
This allows us to prove continuous facts about $V$ by examining only finite subspaces of $V$ spanned by vectors from $H$ and then the fact is automatically proven for the whole space $V$ since the closure of dense subset of a set is the whole set itself.

thank you so much for this answer! really helpful
